# Installing imagemagick on Ubuntu: Unmet Dependencies

Tags: 16.04, apt, imagemagick

On Ubuntu 16.04 I am using:

```
$ sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

to install imagemagick. But however I get the following message and imagemagick is not getting installed:

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done 
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these: 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
imagemagick : Depends: imagemagick-6.q16 (= 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.13)  
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-138-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic but it is not going to be installed  
linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic but it is not going to be installed
                           Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed 
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Maybe I should run `apt-get -f install` as recommended. Is that safe on a production system?

Comment: Just tried the install on my 18.04, and it works. The error message you get points at a deeper underlying problem here. Did you by chance meddle with the kernel installation somehow to downgrade the kernel, or did you upgrade from a previous Ubuntu version to 18.04? As 4.4.0 is not the kernel normally running on 18.04.

Comment: You can install missing packages which caused the unmet dependencies with `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing`.

Comment: @Videonauth As far as I know the system was upgraded from a previous Ubuntu version. Would you recommend a kernel update?

Comment: @MangoD: I would do so, you can do it by `sudo apt update && sudo apt install --reinstall linux-generic`

Comment: @Videonauth Would you generally say this is a safe command to execute? Of course a backup is always needed before performing such task.

Comment: Backup are on production systems anyways mandatory. There is a saying "No backup, no pity". As it is right now your machine is at least booting up and you're being able to make changes and repairs, this state should be conserved in a backup before you try anything.

Comment: @Videonauth True. Is there any further action needed like a server restart to switch to the new kernel?

Comment: Yes a restart is needed here, kernel changes usually only take effect when the machine is newly booted up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89869/discussion-between-videonauth-and-mango-d).

Comment: Ok, thank you. I had to edit my question and correct myself. The running ubuntu version is currently 16.04. Sorry for that mistake I should avoid mixing different things up here.
Is it still necessary to upgrade the kernel?